# Which ml model for selecting one candidate among many

Tags: machine-learning, classification, model-selection

I have an entity matching task and I am struggling to decide which ml model I should use for it. Let me break it down.

I have a complex search query, and for each query I can have from 0 to ~50 results. So far this is quite similar to normal search (in search only relative scores matter). The results are scored based on a weighted sum of different similarity functions. Now among these results I need to select *at most one* that I'm confident a user is looking for. So far, I've approached this simply as classification problem. I have these similarity features that get calculated for each result. Then, whichever score is highest + has a score above a set threshhold gets classified as *the match*. If there is no result with a score above the threshhold, I say there is no match.

It works okay-ish, except often times there are a few results that are above threshold, and pretty close to each other (let's say the threshhold is at 70, and my results have scores {80, 81, 83}). I have a feeling that the fact that there are a few results that have similarly high score should be reflected somehow. I have far less confidence that the top result is a true match if the scores are {80, 81, 83} than if they were, say, {81, 20, 12}. Similarly, even if the top result has a score of 50 (below the 70 threshold), maybe it should be marked as a match if other results are, say in the 0-5 range.

Should I have a second classifier on top of the first one that uses initial score of the candidate and also scores of other candidates as features. Or should I stop treating this problem as classification problem and use smth else completely? If so, is there an ml model to deal with choosing a true match among many candidates?

Thank you